# Angular based collapsible panel Demo in which I want to create a nested collapsible panel

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to create a multilevel collapsible panel.
In the demo If I click on parent collapsible panel, it opens all inner collapsible panels and vice versa.

My requirement is  to have a collapsible panel with child collapsible panels with the same code flow.
In which if I click on parent collapsible heading, then it should open and show its content without opening child collapsible panels.
and so on if I click on inner collapsible heading then it should only open or close its own content which is not happening.

If anyone knows please suggest solutions for this ASAP.

```
[<

!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="group-template.html">
    <div class="panel {{panelClass || 'panel-default'}}">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title" style="color:#fa39c3">
          <a href tabindex="0" class="accordion-toggle" ng-click="toggleOpen()" uib-accordion-transclude="heading"><span
            ng-class="{'text-muted': isDisabled}">{{heading}}</span></a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-collapse collapse" uib-collapse="!isOpen">
        <div class="panel-body" style="text-align: right" ng-transclude></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </script>

  <p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="status.open = !status.open">Toggle last panel</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="status.isFirstDisabled = ! status.isFirstDisabled">Enable / Disable first panel</button>
  </p>

  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="oneAtATime">
      Open only one at a time
    </label>
  </div>
  <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">

    <uib-accordion-group is-open="status.open">
      <uib-accordion-heading>
       heading 1 <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}"></i>
      </uib-accordion-heading>
      content 1
       <uib-accordion-group is-open="status.open">
      <uib-accordion-heading>
       inner panel heading 1 <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}"></i>
      </uib-accordion-heading>
      inner panel content 1
    </uib-accordion-group>
    </uib-accordion-group>
  </uib-accordion>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Plunker Collapsible Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/HGtwbYylJKC68gHOooIT?p=preview)

I tried to remove the attribute [is-open="status.open"] from both parent and child which is making the accordion work but the glyph icons aren't switching.

I want to achieve this requirement with icons working properly......

Answer (score 0):

**Try replacing the child element in your plunkr with this code**

```
      content 1
       <uib-accordion-group is-open="status.openChild">
      <uib-accordion-heading>
       inner panel heading 1 <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.openChild, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.openChild}"></i>
      </uib-accordion-heading>
      inner panel content 1
    </uib-accordion-group>
```

Comment: Basically in our code, We don't have control over child panel, because the implementation is like the parent panel is duplicated over child panel and is created dynamically. So we can't change  the layout of child panel. So if you could help us with some other sample code.